# How exclusion is achieved using monitor in java

Tags: java, concurrency

So Java supports object level monitors. 
So when we create an instance of a class basically we are creating different objects. Now, consider a scenario in which there is a shared data accessed by the all the instances of the object through a method in the object.

Please let me know how the keyword synchronized makes it possible to achieve thread safety in this case because i have different instances (objects) of the same class.

Answer (score 2):

In that case you would synchronize on the object which *is* the data you are accessing.

So, if you have 100 instances of Foo all accessing a piece of data, that data has a single reference. Lets call that reference Bar. Then all your Foos would access Bar while synchronizing on it.

```
void changeBar(){
  synchronized(bar){
    //insert logic here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all instances of the class are accessing a piece of data, you might be using a `static` members:

```
public class Foo {
  private static Object shared;

  public static void accessShared() { /* code */ }
}
```

In that case, you can make the `static` method `synchronized`:

```
public class Foo {
  private static Object shared;

  public static synchronized void accessShared() { /* code */ }
}
```

This is equivalent to the code:

```
public class Foo {
  private static Object shared;

  public static void accessShared() { 
    synchronized (Foo.class) { /* code */ }
  }
}
```

Remember, `Foo.class` is itself an object, and hence has a monitor associated with it.